# Проверить ссылку PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброе время суток.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно проверить ссылку:

```
https://example.com/dir1/dir2/?id=123456789&tok=TXh9Sj8d
```

Где id многозначное число, а tok многозначное строка.

Мой вариант

```
preg_match_all("/id=(\d+)|tok=(\w+)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Comment: что значит "проверить ссылку" и чем вас не устраивает ваш вариант? больше информации.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем `preg_match_all()`? Достаточно `preg_match()`.

Предлагаю такой вариант:

`preg_match('/id=(\d+)&tok=(\w+)$/', $str, $matches)`

Для Вашего примера `$matches` будет

```
MATCH 1
1.  `123456789`
2.  `TXh9Sj8d`
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
$re = "/id=(\\d*)&tok=(.*)/"; 
$str = "id=123456789&tok=TXh9Sj8d"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

[ссылка для теста](https://regex101.com/r/kA0eL7/1)